# Creating Swapfiles

Tags: memory, docker, swap-space

I have a Pi3 hooked up with a [WDLabs PiDrive](http://wdlabs.wd.com/products/wd-pidrive-foundation-edition/#hdd)

I have `Raspbian Lite` installed on the drive and in trying to run some `docker images` simultaneously  some of the images processes are being `"killed"` with a `137 exit code` which is an out of memory error.

I'm assuming it could be the partition or swap size might be too low of size?

I tried creating a swapfile size and got the following output

```
sudo dphys-swapfile setup
```

> want /var/swap=1024MByte, checking existing: deleting wrong size file (104857600), generating swapfile ...
>        of 1024MBytes

`sudo dphys-swapfile swap on`

> swapon: /var/swap: swapon failed: Input/output error

What does this mean? 
Should I try to increasing or decreasing my swapfile? 
Is the RAM being overloaded?
How can i create a swapfile on the PiDrive. I think it does this already but how can I be sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the swap file is still set on the SD card. The process I would use is

- `sudo dphys-swapfile swapoff`
- `sudo nano /etc/dphys-swapfile`
- Set the value of CONF_SWAPFILE in to point to your hard disk mount / partition on the HDD and **REMOVE** the **#** at the start of the line
- Set the value of CONF_SWAPSIZE to the size you want
- `sudo dphys-swapfile setup`
- `sudo dphys-swapfile swapon`

Answer (score 0):

To be 100% sure of an memory overload Error try those
commands:

1. `docker ps -a` to find your Container ID
2. `docker inspect "your Container ID"`.

   - look for the line with `OOMKILL`
   - If `OOMKILL` shows you a `true` it is `100%` a Memory Problem

Another Problem for you Memory Problem could be possible your `Docker log`.
My Image has writing mass lines of outputs into my Docker logs which was the reason why i´ve recieve an `error Code:137` as well

source: https://github.com/DistributedSystemsGroup/zoe/issues/28 + Experience